# ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app) Invalid choice: 'run'

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm trying to get the [golang hello-world bigtable example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-golang/tree/master/examples/bigtable/bigtable-hello) running locally locally and running into this issue. When I run `gcloud preview app run app.yaml` from the `bigtable-hello` directory, I get the following error:

> ➜  bigtable-hello  gcloud preview app run app.yaml
>   Usage: gcloud
>   preview app [optional flags]    group may be
>   modules   command may be         deploy | gen-config
>
> *(BETA)* This set of commands allows you to deploy your app, manage your existing deployments, and also run your app locally.  These
>   commands replace their equivalents in the appcfg tool.
>
> global flags:   Run `gcloud -h` for a description of flags available
>   to all commands.
>
> command groups:   modules                *(BETA)* View and manage your
>   App Engine modules.
>
> commands:   deploy                 *(BETA)* Deploy the local code
>   and/or configuration of
>                            your app to App Engine.   gen-config             *(BETA)* Generate missing configuration files for a
>                            source directory.
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app) Invalid choice: 'run'.
>
> Valid choices are [deploy, gen-config, gen-repo-info-file, instances,
>   modules, services, versions].

I've put the demo files into my local go directory like below:
[image]

Comment: Try using `gcloud beta app run app.yaml`.  I'll ask the author to comment on this tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks, but that gives the same response.

Comment: I've sent him an email asking him to respond here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app run` is no longer part of the gcloud SDK as can be seen under all the possible command trees:

- [`gcloud alpha`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/) has no `app` command group
- [`gcloud app`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/) has no `run` command
- [`gcloud beta`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/app/) has no `run` command
- [`gcloud preview app`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/preview/) has no `app` command group

This was removed with [version 92.0.0](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/release_notes#9200_2016113) released on January 13, 2016.  That changelog recommends using `dev_appserver.py` instead.  An example can be found in [Running the local development server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/using-local-server).

```
> dev_appserver.py src/github.com/jamescharlesworth/bigtable-hello
```

Other flags and options can be found in `dev_appserver.py`'s documentation in [Local Development Server Options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/local-devserver-command).